# "Unable to post message" console error when trying to access Google In-page Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Console log in Chrome is giving me this message constantly when trying to access In-page Analytics:

```
Unable to post message to http://heatma.ps. Recipient has origin https://heatma.ps.
```

I am aware that these two addresses must be exactly the same in order for this feature to work, so I made sure that `Default URL` in `Web Property Settings` is set to be `https://heatma.ps`. I have no idea why Google is still trying to post message to http://heatma.ps instead. I tried clearing cache, tried different browsers to no avail. Any ideas how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question is a combination of javascript code inserted in the site and corresponding google analytics setup. Just b/c the answer turned out to be on the side of web front tool does not mean it's not programming related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that google introduced new version of Analytics.

If you added your site in the old version you will have to make changes in settings using old interface. If you just set it up using new interface the changes will not change settings in the old version, hence you will endup with a confusing information that your new changes did not take place.

**How to fix it**

Switch to the old analytics version ( by clicking `old version` in the top right corrner) and navigate to your sites settings, there look at the `Website URL` filed to verify that it is setup correctly:

[image]